# Onsager's hypothesis: why is true that correlations decay with increasing time?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, non-equilibrium, fluctuation-dissipation

I am studying from Chandler's book (*Introduction to Modern Statistical Mechanics*) the fluctuation-dissipation theorem. Before introducing it, the book states something without really demonstrating it. It says that the **time correlation function** of fluctuations goes to zero when the time difference between the two instants that appear in the formula goes to infinity, namely:

$$C(t)=\int dxf(x)\delta A(t';x)\delta A(t'+t;x) \rightarrow0 \quad as \quad t\rightarrow +\infty$$

where $\delta A(t)$ is the fluctuation  at time $t$ of $A(t)$ from the time-independent average value $\langle A\rangle$, and $f(x)$ is the probability density function of phase space points. This comes from stating that for large $t$ we have
$$\langle \delta A(t')\delta A(t'+t)\rangle\rightarrow\langle\delta A(t')\rangle\langle\delta A(t'+t)\rangle$$
I cannot justify this last statement. Where does it come from? Is it an axiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At equilibrium, one would expect fluctuations $\delta A$ at a time $t'$ and fluctuations at a time $t'+t$ would become statistically independent when $t \rightarrow + \infty$.

The average of a product of statistically independent variables is the product of the averages.

Comment: Thanks. This independence is a postulate based on a reasonable argument, correct?

Comment: @SalvatoreManfrediD It is a reasonable guess for many equilibrium systems. A more formal justification is related to the possibility of proving that the dynamics of the system is *mixing* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics) ), at least in art of the accessible phase space.